# filtering record in client dataset where the record is false

Tags: delphi, filter, tclientdataset

the sI have a clientdataset boolean field named "*Controled*".

I want to filter not controled records.

In Delphi XE (VCL) I was using these code and it was working:

```
ClientDataSet1.Filter := 'Controled = 0';  
ClientDataSet1.Filtered := True;
```

In Delphi XE2 (FMX), this code do not work but I can filter controled records (`Controled =1`) and it work but I want the un-controled records.

Any Idea or it's a but in the new version?

Comment: Can't you mix 0 and NULL? 
Just an idea, as symptoms are somewhat similar.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is a Boolean field, what about "not Controled"? In case the Boolean fields are not properly evaluated by the filter string interpreter, if `Controlled = true` works, you should be fine with either `not (Controled = true)` or `Controled <> true`. Taking your example, that means instead of `Controled = 1` simply write `Controled <> 1`.

Comment: I've found: In LiveBindings by default, when example the BufferCount property of a LinkGripToDataSource is set to -1, it retreive only 200 record (-1 mean 200 record !!!). To avoid this, set LinkGridToDatasource1.BufferCount to a number. you can also set LinkGridToDatasource1.AutoBufferCount to True, for automatically set the number for BufferCount. What I discover, now all work well for previous behavior about filtering Controlled = 0.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test in XE3 shows that the filter works fine if you actually use `True` and `False` (which is what you should have been doing all along).

```
ClientDataSet1.Filter := 'Controled = False';
ClientDataSet1.Filtered := True;
```

The test table I created contains an `integer` field called `ID` and a `Boolean` field called `Controlled` (same as yours, but spelled with 2 Ls).

Test button click code:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientDataSet1.Filtered := False;
  if Edit1.Text <> '' then
  begin
    ClientDataSet1.Filter := Edit1.Text;
    ClientDataSet1.Filtered := True;
  end
  else
    ClientDataSet1.Filter := '';
end;
```

No filter set (`Filtered = False` and `Filter = ''`):

[image: No filter set]

Filter = `Controlled = False`

[image: Filter = False]

Filter = `Controlled = True`

[image: Filter = True]

Comment: Hum Maybe the problem is in the Data, you exemple work for me if I ask Controlled = True but not for Controlled = False.

Comment: I don't know; I can't see your data. I posted images of it working both ways (`True` and `False`), and the code I used to set the filter. As you can see, it uses `Edit1.Text`, and I showed the content of the `Edit1.Text` in all the images. Do you have rows that have `Controled` set to `False`? You haven't explained what "doesn't work" means exactly - are you getting no rows, all rows, or what?

Comment: I'm not getting no rows, Controlled =0 (or False) return all rows. I've drilled more deep, I've test with a new SQLite database and all work well, the problem is with the original MSSQL database. I've also tried to change the boolean field to an integer, so it retrieve Controlled =1 but not Controlled =0 (give all rows). Maybe there is a kind of data corruption or driver mis interpretation. The only think I know is when I work With the original VCL project which I updated to XE2 all work well. This problem appeared when I create anew project in XE3 (FMX).

Comment: I'm not sure what more you want me to do here. I've answered the question you asked (about the filter). I can't analyze your data from here; the code I posted above was written in XE3, and the database stuff is cross-platform so it doesn't matter if it's VCL or FMX. So to repeat what you said: the only thing I know is that the code I posted works perfectly fine in Delphi XE3 with `TClientDataSet`. Now you're throwing SQL Server into the mix, when it's not part of your original question at all. If you have a separate **new** question about SQL Server, post a **new** question. :-)

Comment: Thank Ken, no I do not ask for more now, I'm just add more inputs. What I said about previous version of the project (XE2 VCL project) is that it worked normally. The probled I faced appeared only when I created a new XE3 FMX project against the previous MSSQL Database. More, I created a new table within the same database (MSSQL) and all work perfectly. I assume now it must have some corupt data in the previous MSSQL table (the weird think is that table worked in the VCL version). I will not invertigate anymore as I have a work around. Thanks.

Comment: FINALLY: I've created 4 new application to work with my old table: XE3 (FMX & VCL) and XE2 (FMX and VCL). My conclusion is: the behavior (not filtering Controlled  =0) is present in XE3 (FMX et VCL) and XE2 (FMX). In XE2 (VCL), the code worked corectly to my old table.